# knockoutjs checked binding

Tags: knockout.js

I am having trouble with the `checked` binding: clicking on the checkbox doesn't update the visible status, although a dependentObservable indicates that the value has changed.

Here is the HTML fragment:

```
<input type="checkbox" 
        data-bind="checked: document().selected" 
        title="Select one or more documents to find more similar ones" >
```

This is bound to an instance of my `Posting` class that has a `document()` observable. The relevant part of the document class looks like this:

```
function Document(data, topic) {
    this.id = ko.observable(data.id);
    this.url = ko.observable(data.url);
    this.title = ko.observable(data.title);

    /** Display state **/
    this.selected = ko.observable(false);
    ko.dependentObservable(function() {
        console.log("Selected " + this.url() + " : " + this.selected());
    }, this);

}
```

When I click on the check box, the console prints something like this:

```
Selected http://somedomain.com/doc1.pdf : true
```

and yet the checkbox remains unchecked.

I am using jQuery 1.4.2 and knockout 1.2.1

Other aspects of knockout seem to be working correctly. When I isolated the problem in jsffiddle like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/SbuEV/), it worked as expected. Any thoughts on what I should test next?

Gene

**UPDATE: Dec 12, 2011 2:54 PST:**

@RP Niemeyer: I have many other `dependentObservable` instances; the only one that metnions `selected()` looks like this:

```
this.selectedDocuments = ko.dependentObservable( function() {
    return this.documents().findAll(function(doc) {return doc.selected()});
}, this);
```

`findAll` does what you mighht think.

As far as I can tell, what's happening is that the `selected` observable is set to true when the checkbox is triggered, which fires the dependentObservable, which prints the correct value. The view is not updated, however. Nonetheless, the observable thinks it's set to true, because subsequent clicks on the same (deselected) checkbox do not produce any further console output.

**UPDATE Dec 12, 2011, 9:45 PM PST:**

I was able to reproduce the problem in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SbuEV/7/). If you edit out the click handler on the enclosing div, the checkboxes work correctly. Is there a work-around, or is this a known problem?

Comment: I doubt that this is actually your issue, but make sure that you close your tags.  Your `input` tags are not closed.  This does cause issues in KO with other elements.

Comment: I tried both using the `<input />` and `<input></input>` variants, and produced the same (incorrect) results.

Comment: Do you have any other event handlers on the page (live/delegate) or anything else that is firing when the checkbox is clicked.  Is the other HTML similar to the fiddle?

Comment: I added further details describing the problem.

Comment: Any errors in the console?  Would love to help.  Wish you could get a repro in jsfiddle, but I understand that it is hard to extract from a real app sometimes. I haven't seen this particular type of problem when the checkbox is bound against an observable (as opposed to a dependentObservable).  The other times when this can happen is when using the click binding instead of checked, but not in your case.

Comment: No errors on the console. Interestingly, the checkboxes render properly when I toggle the visible status on the div that contains them. But then they latch again in the selected state; clicking doesn't update the checkbox but does update the underlying model.

Comment: I modified the post again, this time with a JSFiddle that reproduces the problem. It looks like the click handler on an enclosing div is causing the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK- with the updates it makes sense.  What you can do is `return true;` from the click handler that is on the outside div.  This will allow the default action to proceed.

http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/SbuEV/8/

Comment: Should I always 'return true' from ko click-handlers?
What about using the "clickBubble: false" option?

Comment: @AsleG - they have slightly different purposes. Returning `true` will allow the default action to happen ( is actually `event.preventDefault` ). So, when you click a link it would navigate, etc.  `clickBubble: true` would allow the click event to bubble up to handlers on parent elements (`event.stopPropagation`). Hope that helps!