# Checkbox doesn't get checked in knockout

Tags: javascript, asp.net, knockout.js

I have a checkbox and click event for checkbox for updating data. When I click on the checkbox the data is updating but the checkbox does not get not checked.

This is my html code:

```
<td>
 <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: status, disable: status, click: $root.UpdateStatus" />
</td>
```

This is my script:

```
self.UpdateStatus = function (tblUsers) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'SinglePageApp.aspx/UpdateStatus',
        data: "{statusVal: 'true',goalId: " + tblUsers.goalId + "}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (result) {
            alert(result.d);
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(textStatus);
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
    });
};
```

I want my checkbox to get checked when it is clicked. And after that put updated data after checkbox clicked.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**See**: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html

> **Note 3: Allowing the default click action**
>   By default, Knockout will prevent the click event from taking any
>   default action. This means that if you use the click binding on an a
>   tag (a link), for example, the browser will only call your handler
>   function and will not navigate to the link’s href. This is a useful
>   default because when you use the click binding, it’s normally because
>   you’re using the link as part of a UI that manipulates your view
>   model, not as a regular hyperlink to another web page.
>
> However, **if you do want to let the default click action proceed, just
>   return true from your click handler function**.

---

**Edit:** added example showing where to return `true` in the function. It has to be return from the actual function itself, not the Ajax `success` or `error` handler.

```
self.UpdateStatus = function (tblUsers) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'SinglePageApp.aspx/UpdateStatus',
        data: "{statusVal: 'true',goalId: " + tblUsers.goalId + "}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (result) {
            alert(result.d);
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(textStatus);
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
    });
    // Return true to allow default click action.
    return true;
};
```

Comment: I have tested this with your code and it works in both IE9 and Firefox. Make sure your `return true;` is not inside the `$.ajax()` call.

Comment: sorry i am a beginner in knockout.Where should i put return true? I have tried it inside webmethod 'UpdateStatus'.

Comment: thanks Willem Duncan, i have put return true after $.ajax() call.And its working now.

Comment: i want to make checkbox disable after one click.How can it be possible?

Comment: Ty for this answer... I wasn't sure what was causing it to not get checked :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're disabling the checkbox if status = false, but the only way to set status to true is if you check it. That's why the checkbox never gets checked even though knockout knows it's clicked.

Since it's disabled, you won't be able to check the checkbox, so you have to remove the `disable: status` data binding, or place the `disable` logic some place so you can actually change the value of the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the default behavior of event handlers in Knockout is to disable the default action for the event. In this case, your `click` handler does that.

A solution that I recommend is to avoid using the `click` handler and have your `UpdateStatus` run as a subscription to status. In your view model constructor, you should add `self.status.subscribe(self.UpdateStatus, self);`

Another solution is the one mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8490367/1287183) that involves returning `true` from your `click` handler.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/f5Wcy/) and it works when `UpdateStatus` returns `true` (not preventing the value-change) and `status` must obviously be an observable value.