# Allowing checkbox update only on JS confirm using Knockout

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I have blocked out in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2vNBB/5/ the scenario I am trying to achieve.

User clicks a check box and is prompted whether or not they want to alter that setting, however in the fiddle you can see that the checkbox remains checked no matter the action taken but the observable reflects the change.

The check box should have the correct value displayed but it does not.

HTML

```
<div class="checkbox-inline">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: IsAggregate, click: updateAggregate" />
    </label>
</div>
<br/>
<span>This is the observable value: </span><span data-bind="text: IsAggregate"></span>
```

JS

```
 var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.IsAggregate = ko.observable(true);

    self.updateAggregate = function () {
        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to click that?")) {
            self.IsAggregate(self.IsAggregate());      
        } else {
             self.IsAggregate(!self.IsAggregate());  
        }
    };
};

var vm = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

---

UPDATE
This has the functionality I am looking for however I want to wire this into just the checkbox. http://jsfiddle.net/2vNBB/10/

Comment: yo @Zach M. check my answer out with the custom binding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to solve this checkbox problem before, you will need to create a custom binding for yur checkbox. This solution will work as you expect and will not check/uncheck the chebox.

here is the fiddle [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Y8Ubj/1/)

```
ko.bindingHandlers.customChecked = {
     init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
         element.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
            if (confirm('Are you sure you want to click that?'))
            {
               element.checked = !element.checked;
               valueAccessor()(element.checked);          
            }
         });
         element.checked = valueAccessor()();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have had trouble grasping the `valueAccessor` part of these custom bindings, so this is saying, trigger customChecked and pass in the value found at IsAggregate to this function.

Comment: valueAccessor is a function that returns isAggregate observable from your viewmodel.

Comment: using the mousedown handler is more appropriate here.

Answer (score 2):

Return true from your function

```
var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.IsAggregate = ko.observable(true);

    self.updateAggregate = function () {
        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to click that?")) {
            self.IsAggregate(self.IsAggregate());      
        } else {
             self.IsAggregate(!self.IsAggregate());  
        }
        return true;
    };
};
```

Here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Mq8hj/1

Comment: Can you elaborate on why that is the case?

Comment: Sure. Just like returning false in a function prevents the default action from finishing, returning true allows the default action (un/checking the checkbox) to finish.

Comment: This still does not work because it checks/unchecks the checkbox.

Comment: It works with the observable, but still checks/unchecks the checkbox even if you click Cancel (after you click cancel it does reverts it to original state). I am using Chrome Version 34.0.1847.116. In my solution with the custom binding checkbox does not get updated if the user clicks Cancel.

Comment: You are right but he checked'ness of the box reverts back, I do however like your solution as visually it is more accurate to what is happening.

Comment: Agreed. I think it's cleaner for the checkbox to remain in its current state until after responding to the confirm box.

Answer (score 0):

You can also replace the immediate click binding with a custom handler and only change the value of your observable when the option to change has been confirmed. This gives you a little more control over the order in which the bindings are happening. Currently, you actually change the value of your property, then ask to confirm, then either change it back or set it to the same value...

http://jsfiddle.net/2vNBB/11/

```
ko.bindingHandlers.ConfirmCheck = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {        
         var isAggregateObservable = valueAccessor();
        element.checked = isAggregateObservable();

        element.onclick = function() {
            if (confirm("Are you sure you want to click that?")) {
                isAggregateObservable(element.checked);
            } else {
                 element.checked = !element.checked;   
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: onlick - might not work, because once it happens the box is already checked or unchecked.

Comment: same order of operations as your initial example. this handles the click event on the initialization of the binding...then, every time you click, the check changes then the confirmation. If you accept, the value is stored in your observable, otherwise the check is reverted.

Answer (score 0):

I know htis is a bit old, but my pennies worth is tht mark b. nearly had it - return the result of your confirm box from the update:

```
self.updateAggregate = function () {
    var confirmResult;
    
    if ( confirmResult = confirm("Are you sure you want to click that?")) {
        self.IsAggregate(self.IsAggregate());      
    } else {
        self.IsAggregate(!self.IsAggregate());  
    }
    
    return confirmResult;
};
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2vNBB/12/)

[By default knockout returns false to event hanlders which prevents the default action running](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html). see note 3. also this is explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12796044/checkbox-doesnt-get-checked-in-knockout) answer here on stackoverflow...

If you return tru then the default is allowed and the action will continue - your box will be checked. If you return false then it is prevented. So all you need to do is return the result of your confirm.

No custom bindings required.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without making any custom binding by using an anonymous function which calls the confirm, then the removal function if the confirm is true.

```
<input type="button" data-bind="click: function () { var confirmed = 
confirm('Are you sure you want to remove this?');  if(confirmed) 
UpdateCheckbox(this); }">
```